# Problems with accessing protected static List using Reflection

Tags: c#

I'm trying to mod Planetbase and I have to access `protected static List<Character> mCharacters = new List<Character>();` inside public abstract class `Character` in `Planetbase` namespace. Here is my code:

```
FieldInfo characters = typeof(Character).GetField("mCharacters", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
carriedResources = Character.characters.Where(x => x.getLoadedResource() != null)
                .ToDictionary(y => y, x => x.getLoadedResource()); // Get all carried resources across all characters
```

However I'm getting the "Character does not contain the definition for characters" error despite writing a method to access it. No idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `Character.characters` makes no sense: you could do `Character.mCharacters` if you had access, but presumably you have none so you are doing reflection. You need something like `((List<whatever>)characters.GetValue(null)).Where(...` assuming it is actually `static`

Comment: Get and enumerate all fields to troubleshoot an issue with Type.GetFields(BindingFlags....) 

The answer by Tony is accurate for the private/Protected static field., it looks like your understanding of class Character is different from reality.

Is it generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BindingFlags` you are using are not correct. What you need is `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static`. You can find out more about this enumeration [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=net-6.0).

These are some of the most used binding flags when one would search for any type member (field, property, method, etc.):

> `BindingFlags.Public` specifies that public members are to be included in the search.
> `BindingFlags.NonPublic` specifies that non-public members are to be included in the search.
> `BindingFlags.Instance` specifies that instance members are to be included in the search.
> `BindingFlags.Static` specifies that static members are to be included in the search.

Update:
I just noticed that you are not accessing the field information appropriately. After you have the field info, you can access the underlying value like this:

```
FieldInfo field = typeof(Character).GetField("mCharacters", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var value = field.GetValue(__character_instance__);
```

The retrieved value will be of type object so you have to safely convert it to the appropriate type.

So if I have this class:

```
public class Person
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this._name = name;
    }
}
```

I can access the field data like this:

```
var person = new Person("Tony Troeff");
var field = typeof(Person).GetField("_name", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var fieldValue = field.GetValue(person) as string;
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. here is the code after your feedback:

FieldInfo characters = typeof(Character).GetField("mCharacters", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.IgnoreReturn);
            var value = characters.GetValue(characters) as List<Character>;
            carriedResources = value.Where(x => x.getLoadedResource() != null)